# How to concise this code? Get an array's property (title) by a second array's shared property (_id)

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code works but how can I make it more concise? 
In two arrays, we have a common property (_id). With this property, I get a property from array 2. 
More specific: 
Array 'movies' contains items movie with properties '_id' and 'title'. 
Array 'favoritemovies' contains only '_id'.
I want to return the user's list of favorite movies as titles.

```
var favoritemovies = [1111,3333];

const movies = [        
    {_id:1111, title: 'movie1'},    
    {_id:2222, title: 'movie2'},       
    {_id:3333, title: 'movie3'},    
];

var movieTitles = [];

for (var i = 0; i < favoritemovies.length; i++) {      
    var favMovies = movies.filter(movie => movie._id == favoritemovies[i])       

movieTitles.push(favMovies); 

var movieTitlesFlat = movieTitles.flat(); 
} 

for (var i = 0; i < favoritemovies.length; i++) {    
  console.log(movieTitlesFlat[i].title); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce into an object indexed by `_id`, then call `.map` on the `favoritemovies`, for an overall complexity of `O(N)`:

```js
var favoritemovies = [1111,3333];

const movies = [        
    {_id:1111, title: 'movie1'},    
    {_id:2222, title: 'movie2'},       
    {_id:3333, title: 'movie3'},    
];
const moviesById = movies.reduce((a, { _id, title }) => {
  a[_id] = title;
  return a;
}, {});

const titles = favoritemovies.map(id => moviesById[id]);
console.log(titles);
```

(this could also be done with a nested loop operation, but without transforming the `movies` into a map of some sort first, complexity will be `O(N^2)`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use first use `filter()` on `movies` to get all the items whose `_id` is present inside `favoritemovies` then `map()` on the that filtered array to get titles.

```js
var favoritemovies = [1111,3333];

const movies = [        
    {_id:1111, title: 'movie1'},    
    {_id:2222, title: 'movie2'},       
    {_id:3333, title: 'movie3'},    
];

const res = movies.filter(x => favoritemovies.includes(x._id)).map(x => x.title);
console.log(res)
```

The above algorithm will have `O(n ^ 2)` time complexity. It can be made `O(n)` by creating and `Set` from `favoritemovies`

```js
var favoritemovies = [1111,3333];
let favmovset = new Set(favoritemovies)
const movies = [        
    {_id:1111, title: 'movie1'},    
    {_id:2222, title: 'movie2'},       
    {_id:3333, title: 'movie3'},    
];

const res = movies.filter(x => favmovset.has(x._id)).map(x => x.title);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var favoritemovies = [1111,3333];

const movies = [        
    {_id:1111, title: 'movie1'},    
    {_id:2222, title: 'movie2'},       
    {_id:3333, title: 'movie3'},    
];

var movieTitles = movies.filter( (e)=> favoritemovies.includes(e._id));

movieTitles.forEach( (e)=> console.log(e.title));
```